# How to Load a different js file if controller action result is nil

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Here is my controller action: 
*controller/books_controller.rb*

```
def search_book
        @found_book = Book.find_by_token(params[:token_no])

        #once found I am rendering my search_book.js.erb file (with UJS) 
         respond_to do |format|
           format.js
         end
 end
```

Here is my js file to alter my html contents : views/books/search_book.js.erb

```
  $("#found_book").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "book_view") ) %>");
```

If my book is successfully found then rendering a partial via UJS.(Done)

Let's say if my book is not found i.e. if @found_book.nil? is true.
In that case I want to render another partial for my div "found_book". How to do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remember that search_book.js.erb is still erb and thus you can evaluate your instance variable and use a conditional to render the partial you choose.

```
<%- if @found_book.nil? %>
  $("#found_book").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "no_book_view") ) %>");
<%- else %>
  $("#found_book").html("<%= escape_javascript( render(:partial => "book_view") ) %>");
<% end %>
```

Comment: Aaah !  I just missed it, quite easy solution ! 
You hit the target :)